# Why I haven't been able to store different inherited classes in same package manually while it works perfectly in Netbeans IDE?

Tags: java

I have created a folder named `admin` and created two classes `Employee` and `Department` in different `.java` file in that folder. Class `Department` inherits class `Employee` but isn't compiling with the compilation error that class `Employee` not found.

```
package admin;
public class Employee{}
```

The class contains valid codes and is compiled in the `admin` folder. 
Now for class `Department` I used

```
package admin;
public class Department extends Employee{}
```

This code is placed in file `Department.java` in `admin` folder. But this code on compilation gives error

> `Employee` class not Found

[image]

Comment: are you sure? could you provide a screenshot of your folder structure?

Comment: And tell us how you compile your stuff here.

Comment: how do you compile? Could be that you are compiling from the wrong folder.

Comment: You still need to make sure that the root folder of package `admin` is on the classpath

Comment: Are there any imports in you class? maybe it's looking in the old location of your Employee class?

Comment: Also, `Employee` cannot be found because the class named `admin.Employee`. You should specify a full class name with its package. (when you're doing `java` command)

Comment: I tried admin.Employee . But it is still not working